# Set rsh target user to root for every user

Tags: linux, windows, rsh

I'm using windows computers to execute commands on linux via rsh.
The call of rsh are made from one software that specifies the logged on user name to use on the remote host. But that user is not present on target computer. How do I set in the target host that all users in the /root/.rhosts are mapped to root account?

Comment: rsh?  Really, I thought that was dead.  Is there some reason why you haven't switched over to ssh?  Is there some reason why you can't simply point this piece of software at an alternate script/binary that ignores the supplied username, and connects using SSH to a valid account/

Comment: The law of minimum effort. The software comes with **rsh.exe** by default to submit the calculations for the cluster. If I do not find an easy way to do this. I'll have to do what you said, a script with the parameters used for the SSH and installs a ssh client on all Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

Does the software that invokes `rsh` use a single remote user name for all users? 
(E.g., does it always try to log users in to the remote host as “fred”?) 
If so, create an account named “fred” on the target computer. 
If you’re really serious about creating a security hole
by allowing all your users root access, then change fred’s UID to 0,
and, if desired, change its home directory to `/root`.